# Auto-generating datastore indexes in unit tests

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, objectify

> **Configuration:** Maven 3, Objectify, Google-Appengine, Java 7

I'd like to find a way to auto-generate indexes (in the `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` file) using just unit tests. However, although the tests call the datastore query, the file is not generated.

In my project, I use the standard Maven layout:

```
src/
    main/
    test/
target/
```

When running my unit tests with Maven, no `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` file is generated (at least I can't find it anywhere in the project directory). All tests pass, of course.

Is there a way to generate the indexes automatically using just unit tests?

**Here is the `pom.xml` file (updated based on the correct answer):**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.something.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Example</name>
  <description>Example POM for my appengine project.</description>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <gae.version>1.8.1</gae.version>
    <objectify.version>4.0rc1</objectify.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <oauth2>false</oauth2>
          <address>0.0.0.0</address>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- UPDATE: Based on @Amir's answer, I have added this plugin in order to
        -- copy the generated index file to the webapp directory. -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/appengine-generated</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/WEB-INF/appengine-generated</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- UPDATE: This will remove the genreated WEB-INF directory with the mvn clean 
        -- command. -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>WEB-INF</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.8</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>${objectify.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- GAE -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>${gae.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
      <version>${gae.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
      <version>${gae.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
      <version>${gae.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>httpunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpunit</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
      <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
      <version>1.7R4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml files or may be link to a project like github etc. ?

Comment: The project repository is not public, but I have posted the `pom.xml` now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work one way. It's a bit hacky but it does seem to work.

Note that making this work has little to do with maven. The key is to configure the local datastore service to generate datastore-indexes-auto.xml.

**Step 1:** Modify your local datastore service test config to setNoIndexAutoGen(false). Also, **you unfortunately have to comment out the LocalServiceTestHelper tearDown() call** if you want "datastore-indexes-auto.xml" to contain all the indexes required by your tests.

Note that all my datastore tests inherit from PersistenceTestHelper. So this is how I changed it:

```
public class PersistenceTestHelper {

  private LocalServiceTestHelper appEngineHelper;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig dsConfig = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig();
    dsConfig.setNoIndexAutoGen(false);
    appEngineHelper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(dsConfig);
    appEngineHelper.setUp();
    ...
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    // appEngineHelper.tearDown();
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** Execute "mvn test"

**Step 3:** In the directory you executed "mvn test" look for a WEB-INF sub-directory. There you will find "WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml". This is project directory / pom.xml independent.

```
$ pwd
/home/avaliani/src/karma-exchange
$ mvn test
...
$ cat WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml 
<!-- Indices written at Tue, 2 Jul 2013 03:52:26 UTC -->

<datastore-indexes>

    <!-- Used 1 time in query history -->
    <datastore-index kind="Review" ancestor="true" source="auto">
        <property name="+commentCreationDate" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>

    <!-- Used 1 time in query history -->
    <datastore-index kind="Review" ancestor="true" source="auto">
        <property name="commentCreationDate" direction="desc"/>
    </datastore-index>

</datastore-indexes>
```

**Details:**
I'm using "Apache Maven 3.0.4" and App Engine 1.7.7 SDK. My project is integrated with App Engine's maven plugin: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven

My pom.xml:
https://github.com/karma-exchange-org/karma-exchange/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: That's a good approach. I have changed my POM in order to automatically copy the generated file to the target webapp.

Comment: I want to use the same configuration without using mvn, Is it possible?

Comment: It should be if you are using LocalServiceTestHelper (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting). The changes above are about configuring the test helper so that index usage information is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having your `datastore-indexes.xml` file as something of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
</datastore-indexes>
```